# Использование PHP в HTML<select>

Tags: php, html, база-данных, postgresql

Моя задача состоит в том , чтобы в раскрывающемся списке показывались те детали, которые лежат в таблице , но на деле получаю пустой список, вот мой код

```
 <?php
        require("connect.php");
        $query = "SELECT n_det FROM pmib6411.p";
        $details = pg_fetch_all(pg_query( $dbconn, $query));
         foreach($details as $pp):?>
            <option value="<?=$pp['n_det']?>"><?=$pp['n_det']?></option>
      <?php endforeach?>
```

Если это важно , то Субд - PostgreSQL 9.3.10

Comment: Значит, из базы не приходит ничего. Проверьте, что у Вас в $details, существует ли $detail['n_det'] и какое значение там хранится

Comment: Сделай `print_r($details)` посмотри есть ли там данные? Или включи вывод ошибок `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`, и если $details пустой, то выйдет ошибка, что недостаточно аргументов для foreach

Comment: @DmitriySaxarov Действительно, данные отсутствуют , изменил код в самом вопросе, но он по прежнему не работает, не могли бы вы дать совет как исправить ?

Comment: А с БД коннектится? Попробуйте отладить хоть так `$result = pg_query( $dbconn, $query)` и посмотрите, что там, либо просто `pg_last_error($dbconn)`. Более подробно напишу в ответе.

Comment: @DmitrySaxarov  $result = pg_query( $dbconn, $query) Выдает список деталей , все в порядке
Я так понимаю, что проблема кроется конкретно в теге option и его неправильной вставкой в код

Comment: Мда, изменил ответ попробуйте так. Если не поможет, то открывайте отладчик браузера и смотрите как там выстроены option в select

Comment: Изменил ответ. В торопях написал `echo(getOption())`, но в аргумент функции нужно отправить массив, с которым она будет работать `echo(getOption($details))`. Либо отправить объект, а в функции добавить `$details = pg_fetch_all($details)`

Comment: Почитал немного документации по `pg_fetch_all` и изменил ответ, думаю, что теперь точно поможет)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не работал с БД PostgreSQL, но по документации [pg_fetch_all](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.pg-fetch-all.php) возвращает многомерный массив такого вида

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Fred
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Bob
        )
)
```

Поэтому вам нужно будет сделать так

```
<?php
//...
$details = pg_fetch_all(pg_query( $dbconn, $query));
$data = '';
foreach($details as $pp){
    foreach($pp as $value){
        $data .= '<option value="'.$value['n_det'].'">'.$value['n_det'].'</option>';
    }
}
//...
?>
<select><?php echo($data) ?></select>
```

Либо, если pg_query возвращает такой же объект, как mysqli_query, то можно сделать просто

```
<?php
//...
$details = pg_query( $dbconn, $query );
$data = '';
foreach ($details as $pp){
    $data .= '<option value="'.$pp['n_det'].'">'.$pp['n_det'].'</option>';
}
//...
?>
<select><?php echo($data) ?></select>
```

А лучше всего перед и при использовании `foreach` проверяйте массивы и объекты функцией `print_r`. Так вы будете знать, сколько вложенностей в вашем массиве и вообще есть ли данные в массиве... 
Предыдущий ответ пока не удаляю.

<del>Попробуйте так, чтобы увидеть, где у вас ошибка</del>

```
<?php 
require("connect.php");
$query = "SELECT n_det FROM pmib6411.p";

if (!pg_connection_busy($dbconn)) {
    pg_send_query($dbconn, $query);
}
$result = pg_get_result($dbconn);
if (!pg_result_error || pg_result_error == ''){
    $details = pg_fetch_all($result);
    //тут ваш цикл и все, что нужно
} else {
    echo pg_result_error($result);
    //так вы увидите, где ваша ошибка...
}    
?>
```

<del>Подробнее о [pg_result_error](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.pg-result-error.php) читайте в документации. В вашем случае условие возможно должно быть изменено, т.к. при ошибке не связанной с параметром `$result` вернется FALSE, а если ошибки нет, то вернется пустая строка (`if(pg_result_error == ''){...}`)</del>

<del>Попробуйте так вывести в option</del>

```
function getOption($details){
    $data = '';
    foreach ($details as $value){
        $data .= '<option value="'.$value['n_det'].'">'.$value['n_det'].'</option>';
    }
return $data;
}
```

<del>А в `<select><?php echo(getOption($details))?></select>`</del>